# XML attributes and their corresponding related methods

Tags: android

I am new to Android development and am currently enjoying it a lot.

I have been building a UI by using the XML file and found it quite easy to build a static UI.

Now, I need to build a UI where one of the TextView positions changes during runtime.

Can this be done using XML only?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AbsoluteLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"

    >
<TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="0%"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/percent"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:layout_x="41dip"
        android:layout_y="295dip">
    </TextView>

</AbsoluteLayout>
```

Now I can position the TextView anywhere by changing the value of `layout_x` and `layout_y`. But how to do this at runtime?

I have tried this:

```
TextView text;

text=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.percent);
```

Doing `text.setText("This can be done");` would easily change the text during run time, but how can I change the postion from code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If trying out this by using absolute layout, take a look at the following code.

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AbsoluteLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<TextView
    android:text="@string/hello"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true">
</TextView>

<EditText
    android:hint="xcor"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/xcor"
    android:background="@drawable/select"
    android:layout_x="165dip"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_y="64dip">
</EditText>
<EditText
    android:hint="ycor"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/ycor"
    android:layout_x="168dip"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_y="168dip">
</EditText>
    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:text="Set Position"
        android:layout_x="218dip"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_y="278dip"
        android:background="@drawable/select"
        >
    </Button>
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

CustomPosition.java

```
public class CustomPosition extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(MarginLayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, MarginLayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 150, 50);

    TextView text;
    EditText xcor;
    EditText ycor;
    Button button;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        text=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        xcor=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.xcor);
        ycor=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.ycor);
        button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                params.x=Integer.parseInt(xcor.getText().toString());
                params.y=Integer.parseInt(ycor.getText().toString());
                text.setLayoutParams(params);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, **absolute layout is deprecated**, use relative layout instead, Frame-Layout.

Then use,

```
LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams( MarginLayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, MarginLayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

If asked to import, use import selected layoutparams.

After that use

```
params.leftmargin
```

or

```
params.rightmargin
```

for changing the position.