# Define by code attribute of view

Tags: android, android-view

How do I define by code the attribute of view?

For example, how can I define this image button with this attribute (width, height, margin top, etc)?

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/add_butt1"
    android:layout_width="35dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:src="@drawable/button_state" 
/>
```

Comment: see this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5389405/xml-attributes-and-their-corresponding-related-methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about layout_ attributes - than it can be defined with LayoutParams inner class of the layout, in which you want to add your view. For example you can use this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html if you will add your view to RelativeLayout.

```
        RelativeLayout layout = findViewById(R.id.my_layout);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.leftMargin = 10; //px
        layout.addView(new TextView(this), params);
```

Comment: and if i dont use WRAP_CONTENT in my view and if use the dimension in dp for my view ?

Comment: No problem, just pass pixel value instead of WRAP_CONTENT.
You can get it with 
getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.id) or
getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.id)